# Rails 3 and Prawn in own action

Tags: ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.1, prawn

I have the action `my_pdfs` and there I have followings:

```
def my_pdfs
   respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf { render :layout => false }
   end
end
```

In the `views/mycontroller` is the file **my_pdfs.html.erb** and **my_pdfs.pdf.prawn**.
How can I display the generated PDF? I tried something like:

`localhost:3000/controller/my_pdfs/my_pdfs.pdf`, but this is a bad way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658302/unable-to-render-pdf-to-browser-using-prawn-pdf-for-ruby-on-rails) will help you.

It already have a good solution by using **send_data**.

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController  

  def my_action
    doc = PdfGenerator.new(some_params)
    doc.generate

    send_data doc.render, filename: 'preview only.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
  end
```