# Unable to render PDF to browser using Prawn PDF for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, prawn

I am creating a pdf file in the latest version of the Prawn library (v1.0.1rc) in Rails (3.1.1) and when I run my code it generates the PDF into the root of the application.

I don't want this. I want it to render the output into user's browser window, without saving it locally to the server.

Please tell me how I can achieve this. Here are my files:

**views/foo/show.pdf.erb**:

```
<%=

require 'prawn'

pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => 'LETTER', :page_layout => :landscape, :margin => 50, :top_margin => 20, :bottom_margin => 50)

.....

render_file("foo.pdf")

%>
```

**controllers/foo_controller**:

```
class AuditsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  layout 'application'
  can_edit_on_the_spot
  respond_to :html, :xml, :js, :pdf

  def index
    @audits = Audit.all
    respond_with @audits
  end

  def show
    @audit = Audit.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @audit do |format|
      format.pdf { render :layour => false }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'prawn'
```

**/config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

**AuditsController**

```
def show
  @audit = Audit.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      pdf = Prawn::Document.new
      pdf.text "This is an audit."
      # Use whatever prawn methods you need on the pdf object to generate the PDF file right here.

      send_data pdf.render, type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
      # send_data renders the pdf on the client side rather than saving it on the server filesystem.
      # Inline disposition renders it in the browser rather than making it a file download.
    end
  end
end
```

I used to use the `prawnto` gem before Rails 3.1, but it doesn't work without a bit of hacking anymore. This is a much cleaner way to instantiate and display the PDF object in 3.1 by accessing Prawn directly.

I got this technique straight from one of Ryan Bates' [Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com). Been using it ever since. You can view that specific episode [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised). He goes into much more detail about subclassing Prawn and moving the PDF generating code out of the controller. Also shows a lot of useful Prawn methods to get you started. Highly recommended.

A lot of the episodes are free, but that revised Prawn episode is one of those that are only available with a paid subscription. At $9/month though, a subscription quickly pays for itself.

Comment: Thanks Vickash. That certainly worked and I agree on the subscription point - well worth it!

Comment: Is there a way to do this implicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to send a pdf to the client's browser is to put the download into a link. Often you need to generate a pdf after form submission, but also need to redirect to another page.

**You can't redirect and send the pdf simultaneously**, but you can redirect and then provide a download link, like so:

First add `gem 'prawn'` to your gemfile. Bundle. Then do the following:

Link to your special printing action in your view

```
<%= link_to 'print ticket', print_ticket_path %>
```

route to special printing action in routes.rb

```
match 'print_ticket', to: 'tickets#print_ticket'
```

action that sends the outputted file (change per your needs):

```
  def print_ticket
    if session[:token]
      @pdf = generate_pdf(session[:token])
      send_data(@pdf, :filename => "output.pdf", :type => "application/pdf")
    end
  end

  private 
  def generate_pdf(token)
    Prawn::Document.new do
        formatted_text [ { :text=>"xxx.org", :styles => [:bold], :size => 30 } ]
        move_down 20
        text "Please proceed to the following web address:" 
        move_down 20
        text "http://xxx.org/finder"
        move_down 20
        text "and enter this code:"
        move_down 20
        formatted_text [ { :text=>token, :styles => [:bold], :size => 20 } ]
    end.render 
  end
```